# Frases en español que usan palabras que empiezan todas sucesivamente por a, b, c, d, ... hasta la z

Tags: uso-de-palabras, alfabeto, curiosidades

Estoy buscando frases en español que usan palabras que empiezan todas sucesivamente por a, b, c, d... hasta la z.

Un ejemplo es este, sin contar la ñ ni la w :

> Antes, bienintencionadamente, caminaba determinado, estirándome
>   febrilmente, gozando hábilmente, iluminado, jocoso; kilos lacerados
>   menguando, noblemente ocultando partes que, raras, sobraban
>   tenuemente, usando valoraciones xilofónicas ya zanjadas.

¿Pero existen, acaso, frases así, en español, en que además, la longitud de cada palabra sucesiva sea de uno más o bien de uno menos (en número de letras), que la palabra anterior?

(Editado el 16/10/2015)

Decía Jorge Luis Borges que una periodista le había un día preguntado sobre una situación concreta en Hispanoamérica y que, al contestar él que le producía tristeza, aquélla le había instado a precisar; cuando tristeza, decía Jorge Luis, es una de las palabras más definidas de la lengua española.
Algún "periodista" de esta casa, en algún comentario, me ha pedido que precise las reglas de este juego. No es necesario.  Cuando se afirma, en correcto español, que: *«la longitud de cada palabra sucesiva sea de uno más o bien de uno menos (en número de letras), que la palabra anterior»*, no se ha dicho que la longitud de cada palabra sea uniformemente de uno más que la anterior. La lengua, el español, es en este caso autosuficiente, describe perfectamente bien las condiciones.

Copio y pego aquí -pero copio ligero y pego sin ensañarme- el comentario que escribí sobre la sucesión de las longitudes de cada palabra y que la gente, está visto, no se digna a leer:

> Sea *l* la longitud en número de letras de la primera palabra. Entonces, la sucesión de las longitudes de las palabras de la frase, será: 
>   *l*, *l* + 1, *l* + 2, ..., *l* + *k*, *l* + *k* - 1, *l* + *k* - 2, ..., *l* + *k* - *n*, llegando a una longitud máxima de *l* + *k* y decreciendo con pasos de -1 después. Por ejemplo : 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4 , 3, 2, 1. En este ejemplo *l* = 3, *k* = 11, *n* = 13 lo que nos da un total de *k* + *n* + 1 = 25 palabras (sin la W ni la Ñ).

También puede ser l, l + 1, l, l + 1, l, l + 1, ... para cualquier l por determinar. O bien l, l+1, l+2, l+3, l+2, l+1, l+2, l+3, l+4, l+5, l+6, l+5, l+4, l+5, ...
Hay muchas variedades posibles. O bien l, l+1, l+2, l+1, l, l+1, l+2, ... O bien l, l+1, l+2, l+3, l+2, l+1, l, l+1, l+2, l+3, ... A los que les gusta andar con palabras muy largas, también pueden hacerlo, por supuesto.

Comment: Sólo para facilitar la búsqueda a los interesados: a este tipo de construcciones (sin la constricción de la longitud de las palabras), se les suele llamar «abecegramas».

Comment: Interesante! Aunque me suena a otra pregunta con muchas respuestas posibles...

Comment: A diferencia de las matemáticas, donde hay demostraciones de que algo _no puede ser_ o _puede ser_, con el lenguaje no tenemos esa seguridad. Podemos tener contraejemplos (alguien ha encontrado uno de estos abecegramas) o de momento nadie ha dado con ninguno válido con las restricciones descritas (no sabemos). Un factor fundamental, sería que los idiomas están "vivos" y si bien ahora puede que el DRAE no incluya una palabra con "ñ" válida para incluir en el acebegrama del ejemplo, lo mismo en X años se acuña un término nuevo, la RAE lo acepta y tienes posibilidades que antes no tenías.

Comment: @Joze, creo que la pregunta no pide _abecegramas_, sino si puede o no puede existir uno como el que se describe. Es más bien una pregunta de "sí o no y por qué". En cualquier caso, quizá las respuestas estén sujetas a opinión (aunque no estoy seguro, y por eso no quiero VTC como "opinion based").

Comment: @Diego Si estoy de acuerdo es un poco ambiguo. Es por eso que la dejé abierta. Veamos qué dicen los otros, estoy intrigado.

Comment: @Diego como ha indicado TreeHouse, tendría que existir una palabra de 27 letras que empiece con z.  Los verbos más largos con *z-* son *zancadillear, zaparrastrar, zarzaparrillar, zascandilear*.  Podríamos tener algo como **zancadillearíamonostelos** que nos llega a 24 (1ª persona plural del condicional, reflexivo en función indirecta con dativo ético y objecto directo plural en posposición), pero solo si fuese posible con esos verbos.  El adjetivo más largo con *z-* es *zaparrastroso/zarrapastroso*.  Podríamos llegar a solo 22 con **zaparrastrosísimamente** (superlativo sintético, adverbiado)

Comment: Peor, incluso para *y* (cuyo verbo más largo es «yuxtaponer», y los adjetivos más largos son «yuxtapuesto» y «yuglandáceo», que no admiten superlativo sintético), la *x* (xerográfiquísimamente), y la *w* (washingtonianísimamente — dudablemente posible — con 24).  La *v* va mejor quizás con «videoconferencia» sobre la cual se podría, tal vez, formar «videoconferencialísimamente» con 27 letras),

Comment: @guifa No pienso que la pregunta se refiera a si hay palabras de 27 letras, sino más bien a frases compuestas de palabras que empiecen con las letras del abecedario en orden. Supongo que la regla que se presta a confusión es sobre la longitud de la palabras, como la interpreto, puede que una frase esté compuesta de palabras de longitud 3,4,3,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,3.... sin que la regla se rompa.

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo con Joze. Queda demostrado que el abecegrama completo existe. Respecto a uno con la restricción impuesta, puede estar muy claro que no existe si empezamos por una palabra de cierta longitud. No es tanto encontrar una palabra de 27 letras con Z sino una con B de 25 o 27 si empezamos con una palabra con A de 26. Lo que no creo es que exista una especie de "demostración matemática" que pruebe o refute que un abecegrama con ciertos valores para I o K (según la regla dada en otro de los comentarios) puede existir, o que incluso dijese para qué valores puede existir.

Comment: @Diego pero encontrar una palabra de 27 letras con Z sí es difícil porque, ya he repasado un dicionario, y la palabra más larga no puede llegar, da igual su flexión. Si es imposible con la Z, no tenemos por qué preocuparnos con las demás letras. Con A sería fácil con 27 o más (con varios prefijos/sufijos y al final anti-) pero sería igual de fácil probar (como hice con Z,Y y X) que para otras letras no sería posible llegar encima de los 20 pico, así imposibilitando el ejercicio. Si es como dice que Joze, el OP debe editar porque a mí me suena como de una serie A,B+1,C+2,D+3,E+4 (o al revés).

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta sobre la extensión y construcción de palabras tan largas, jugando en un abecegrama, es imposible en el español. Esto porque no es una lengua aglutinante, como sí lo es el alemán, por ejemplo. Por eso, considerando que la palabra más larga reconocida por la RAE, tiene 23 letras. Si mal no recuerdo es electroencefalografista. Saludos

Answer (score 7):

Estas frases se llaman "abecegramas". Encontré un sitio de web acerca de estas frases: http://www.juegosdepalabras.com/abc/abecegrama.htm

Un ejemplo (con ñ y w):

> Anoche brillaron cerca, dos estrellas fugaces, gravitaban
>   hermosas iluminando juntas Kilométricos lugares; llevaban mágicos
>   negros ñublos; originaban planetas que relucían surcando tenues
>   universos,...vertiendo wolframio, xenón y zafiros.

Creo que no hay abecegramas que sigan tu regla de longitud. No existen palabras de 27 letras (o de 26 sin ñ) que empiecen con una z. También, sería difícil encontrar palabras bastante largas que empiecen con una a, b, c, etc, y casi imposible crear una frase coherente con esas palabras.

Comment: Gracias Treehouse; though why did´nt you read the commentaries before saying this is not possible ?  ¡ Imposible no es un palabra española !

Answer (score 4):

Nadie dijo que la frase tuviera que tener sentido. He aquí una frase que podría cumplir con lo que has solicitado, así totalmente improvisada. Reto a cualquiera a que se invente una con más sentido, si es capaz. :) La formateo para que se vea que cada palabra tiene una longitud de una unidad más o menos que la anterior.

```
Albert
bizqueó
contento
después,
entrando
finamente,
gracioso,
humilde,
inquieto,
jugando
kafkiano
locamente
mientras
nublaba,
ñublos
oscilan,
pensando,
quietos
retumban,
sollozo,
tétricos,
untando
viento,
walkman
xecudo,
yerba
zoca.
```

Más o menos bien hasta las últimas palabras en las que derrapo estrepitosamente, pero es que el final del alfabeto se las trae. Esta frase la llega a coger [Moebius](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Giraud) y te hace un cómic de 8 páginas.

Se admiten interpretaciones y comentarios. :D Podéis comprobar que todas aparecen en el DRAE (sí, incluyendo *[walkman](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c65RhUj)*). Me permito usar un nombre propio para empezar la frase.

Comment: La parte final flaquea, sí, pero +1 por hacerme reir.

Answer (score 2):

Técnicamente, es imposible.

Habría que empezar con palabras de 26 letras e ir disminuyendo. Pero las palabras tan largas en español son muy limitadas, y se restringen a tecnicismos.

> Electroencefalográfico

Sería necesario encadenar tecnicismos sin intercalar ningún determinante, conjunción, verbo o adjetivo. Gramaticalmente no tiene sentido.

Comment: No; la condición es que la longitud de cada palabra sea de uno más *o bien de uno menos· que la precedente; de manera que se puede hacer de la siguiente forma :  5,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,12,13,14,15,16,15,14,13,12,.... siendo los números las sucesivas longitudes de las palabras y empezando casi por cualquier número. Se pueden evitar la palabras muy largas.

Comment: @user55514 en _uno más o bien de uno menos que la precedente_, ¿es constante la diferencia entre uno y el siguiente? Es decir, ¿se puede hacer 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4... o siempre tiene que crecer o decrecer?

Comment: Sí, se puede perfectamente hacer como tú lo planteas; aunque yo lo imaginé más bien así : l, l+1, l+2,..., l+k, l+k-1, l+k-2,...,l+k-n, llegando a una longitud máxima de l+k y decreciendo con pasos de -1 después. Por ejemplo : 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7,  6,  5,  4 , 3,  2, 1.  En este ejemplo l = 3, k = 11, n = 13 lo que nos da un total de  k + n + 1 = 25 palabras (sin la w ni la ñ).

Comment: @user55514, quizá deberías incluir este comentario en la pregunta para clarificar también la regla. Si fijamos I antes de buscar el abecegrama la respuesta es probablemente "no" (porque lo mismo si elijo I=15 no puedo encontrar una palabra con A, o una con B de 16 letras). Si I y K son variables (o incluso si juego con +/- 1 para cada siguiente palabra) la respuesta puede depender todavía del diccionario, y es muy difícil obtener una respuesta segura a menos que sea encontrando un abecegrama que funcione. Cómo saber que "teóricamente existe uno pero no se nos ha ocurrido"?

Comment: Para Diego : ¿ Esto qué es ? : ""Arte bizco calizo, dejador eferente, flagrante guitarrero, histríonico impenetrable....."

Comment: @user55514, es muchas cosas. Es el inicio de un abecegrama en que cada palabra tiene una letra más que la anterior. Es también una frase sin mucho sentido. "Arte bizco calizo" todavía puede tomarse como un recurso poético pero al añadir "dejador eferente" ya pasamos de lo abstracto a lo sin sentido. Es un punto interesante: el abecegrama debe tener sentido. Porque si no en lugar de una frase coherente podemos buscar palabras sueltas que cumplan la regla. Los ejemplos de Treehouse o el de tu pregunta tienen sentido y coherencia. "Arte bizco calizo, dejador eferente" no lo tiene. Es puro absurdo

Comment: Bueno Diego; entonces confío en que tú inventes una frase con estas reglas y que sí tenga sentido y no sea absurda. A mí, lo que me pasa es que me gusta el absurdo, los contrasentidos, el surrealismo. Si lees "El Extranjero" de Albert  Camus, verás que se habla de ello . Decía por otra parte Lewis Carrol que las palabras tienen el sentido exacto de lo que los que tienen el poder, quieren exactamente que tengan; y no se equivocaba nada.

Comment: @user55514, por qué me toca a mi inventar una? Tú has lanzado la pregunta y yo simplemente he ayudado a clarificar lo que se pretendía. Tampoco creo que puedas enfadarte con los otros usuarios porque "no se dignen a leer" todos lo comentarios de cada pregunta, o no hayan entendido bien "la regla". La pregunta era el sitio donde explicar la regla, no los comentarios, y los muchos que hay dan fe de que eran necesarias más explicaciones del abecegrama que intentabas lograr (o saber si no podía existir). En cualquier caso, suerte. Yo dejo ya este hilo, que parece que "estorbo" más que ayudo.

Comment: Estorbas; Diego; estorbas..

Comment: Bueno, no; Diego; quédate.. Me gustaría que buscaras y encontraras un Integrograma con sentido (pero no consentido). http://lit-et-raire.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/integrograma-de-palabras-de-longitud.html

Answer (score 1):

Cuando vi esta entrado no podía dejarla pasar. Esto se me ocurrió a mí, aunque no cumple con la regla de la longitud, y en algunos casos agregue otra palabra para que tuviera un poco más de sentido

```
A   ANTES
B   BIEN
C   CURADO
D   DECÍAN
E   ELLOS
F   FUERTES
G   GOZARON
H   HIJOS
I   ILUSTRES
J   JUNTAMOS
K   KARMA
L   LLORAMOS
M   MORIMOS
N   NACIMOS
Ñ   ÑINGA
O   OPACA
P   del PASADO
Q   QUISIMOS
R   REÍR
S   SOÑAR
T   TUVIMOS
U   QUE
V   UBICAR
W   WHISKY
X   en XOCHIMILCO
Y   YA
Z   ZARPAMOS
```